# When you click on TextField, Sphere, which was on background, go to foreground

Tags: javafx

I want to make a program in which the sphere "Planet" will unfold in the direction of the coordinate that we enter in TextFields. But also there will be buttons that increase the size. Therefore, the sphere is located behind the PNG image, which is called "Interface", with emptiness. The problem is that everything is fine at startup, but when you click on a textField, the sphere shifts to the foreground.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.image.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.*;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainProgram extends Application {

    private static final double AppWidth  = 1500;
    private static final double AppHeight = 1000;
    private static double X = 0;
    private static double Y = 0;
    public static Sphere Planet = new Sphere(600);

    public Group Earth() {

         Planet.setTranslateX(500);
         Planet.setTranslateY(500);
         PhongMaterial EarthMaterial = new PhongMaterial();
         EarthMaterial.setDiffuseMap(new Image("images/DefultMap.jpg"));
         EarthMaterial.setBumpMap(new Image("images/ReliefMap.jpg"));
         EarthMaterial.setSpecularMap(new Image("images/SpecularMap.jpg"));
         Planet.setMaterial(EarthMaterial);
         return new Group(Planet);
    }

    public Group TextSet() {

        TextField FieldX = new TextField();
        FieldX.setFont(new Font("TimesNewRoman", 25));
        FieldX.setPrefWidth(110);
        FieldX.setTranslateX(1060);
        FieldX.setTranslateY(400);

        TextField FieldY = new TextField();
        FieldY.setFont(new Font("TimesNewRoman", 25));
        FieldY.setPrefWidth(110);
        FieldY.setTranslateX(1280);
        FieldY.setTranslateY(400);

        return new Group(FieldX, FieldY);
    }

    public Group CreateGroup() {
        Rectangle Background = new Rectangle(0, 0, (int)AppWidth, (int)AppHeight);
        Background.setFill(Color.BLACK);

        ImageView Interface = new ImageView(new Image("images/Interface.png"));         

        return new Group(Background, Earth(), Interface, TextSet());
    }
    public void start(Stage MainStage) {
        Group MainGroup = CreateGroup();
        Pane MainPane = new Pane(MainGroup);
        Scene MainScene = new Scene(MainPane, AppWidth, AppHeight); 
        MainStage.setScene(MainScene);
        MainStage.setTitle("EarthViewer.exe");
        MainStage.setResizable(false);
        MainStage.getIcons().add(new Image("images/PlanetIcon.png"));
        MainStage.setMaxHeight(1030);
        MainStage.setMaxWidth(1500);
        MainStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

[Before Clicking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPNiN.jpg)

[After Clicking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFpEg.png)

I noticed that when you click on the arrows everything becomes normal again.

Comment: Check this link http://java-buddy.blogspot.com/2013/07/move-node-to-front.html I think there is a move to Back and move to Front cmd

Comment: I am no expert at this subject. Here is my guess. Normally when I see questions that have both 2D and 3D object, They use a [`SubScene`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/SubScene.html) to hold the 3D part.

Comment: Thanks for answers. I found that this is due to TextField itself, which intersect with the sphere. Perhaps this is a bug.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug. If you read the SubScene javadoc, it says that one use-case when mixing 3D and 2D nodes. TextFields are 2D nodes and that Sphere is a 3D Node.